# Windows 8.1 Won't stay asleep

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

As the title indicates, my 8.1 Windows PC will not stay asleep.

-I have globally disabled all wake timers through the power options, and verified that there are no active wake timers via the powercfg -waketimers command

-I have disallowed every device from waking my computer except for the keyboard, and verified that only the computer can wake the computer via the powercfg -devicequery wake_armed command

-I have tried finding what is waking my computer up using powercfg -lastwake, and it shows a Wake History Count of 1, but a Wake History of 0 and a Wake Source Count of 0.

I am at somewhat of a loss. As far as I can tell, nothing except my keyboard can the system, yet every time I put it to sleep it wakes up in half an hour or so (the timing is not specific, and is sometimes significantly shorter or longer).

Anyone have any ideas?